# Asp.net MVC3:How to put username text from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, layout

I'm loading the name of id of the user any view with:

```
var oUser = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 6));
    if (oUser == null || (oUser.firstname == null|| oUser.lastname == null))
        ViewBag.User = User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 6);
    else
        ViewBag.User = oUser.firstname + " " + oUser.lastname;
```

But i want to have the user name string in the _layout every time instead of being loading it every time.
Loading it to a viewbag could be a posibility, but i don't know where to put the code to pass the fields to the layout.

by the way, this won't work and it's not what i'm looking for:

```
 @if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
        <text>Welcome <b>@Context.User.Identity.Name</b>!
        [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
    }
    else {
        @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
    }
```

Comment: Move the first bit of code into your layout file?  You will probably need to incase it in `@{ }` and modify it a bit to show the name, not just put it into a var.

Comment: Why can't you store the username in session?

Comment: @Mark i need an object called user loaded with data, not the username from the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the easiest solution for registering javascript from the controller was quite obvious, but frustrating for someone who's new to the pattern:

Using named sections we find a place for put the javascript

You can use **[Named Sections][1].**

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js)">
    @RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
</head>
```

and this code for the view

**_SomeView.cshtml**

```
@section JavaScript
{
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.message)
}
```

**and in the controller we put**

```
ViewBag.message = @"<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>alert(""Hello World!"")</script>"; ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Following what you said:

Move this code into _layout

```
@{
  var oUser = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 6));
     if (oUser == null || (oUser.firstname == null|| oUser.lastname == null))
        ViewBag.User = User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 6);
     else
        ViewBag.User = oUser.firstname + " " + oUser.lastname;
 }

 @ViewBag.User
```

Where the first bit is now running as code in _layout. And the last line just tells it to write the String in Viewbag.User to screen.

Comment: @Milo so what you want to do is store the name of the active user? Use cookies. When they log in, save the users data to the session cookie. Then use the session cookie's value to display the name. MVC comes with a Users template, which is very easily adapted to your own database to store your users name, and display it. You say its not what your looking for, but unless you store it in a cookie, there is no better way of storing, except getting it on query each time.

Comment: Just to extend on this, convert your User class to a string when they log in, with some parse token seperator like `|`. Then you can store your class in the Cookie String. Then When you read from cookie, parse it on the `|` to get your user class back. You can write a helper method or something for this. Or, just use your own cookie to store all the fields in. I just needed Username, and Name. So I tokenised them together in a secure cookie.